# LESS css variable possibilities/restrictions/syntax usage

Tags: css, less, var

I begun to use the LESS library **exactly 2 hours ago**.
( Time counted AFTER a successfull *kind of a Hello World* )

---

My LESS style sheet **works**.
Here is how I call it in my page:

```
<!-- LESS CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="myLessCssStyle.less" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.1/less.js"></script>
```

I made the equivalent of a *Hello world* on a single CSS value easy to verify:

```
@testDisplay: none;

#bigVisibleElement{
    display: @testDisplay;
}
```

**Success!**
Happy about that, since it was almost too easy...
I started to implement this *serious variable handling advantage* in a small test style sheet I was working on.

**And here is where i'm stucked:**

```
/* my LESS vars definition */

@Bes_ease_in_finish: 10%;
@Bes_ease_out_begin: 80%;
@Bes_ease_out_finish: 90%;

/* A couple more lines that includes other working LESS vars... */

/* This is bugging here. On the first LESS var. */
@keyframes KeyFrame_Bes_Web { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease_in; }
    @Bes_ease_in_finish { opacity: 1; }                      /* <--- Line 75 is here. */
    @Bes_ease_out_begin { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    @Bes_ease_out_finish { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

I defined all other prefix variants of `@keyframes` (-webkit-, -moz-, -o-, -ms-).
That isn't the problem.

Here is the error I get in console:

[image: LESS-variable-usage]

**«Unrecognised input».**

Arrrg... What ?!?
Can't use a LESS vars on these animation timing ?
Why?

Or HOW?
Is there a syntax trick ?

These timing values repeat 5 times FOR EACH animation because of these sickening prefixes... And this is a really simple `@keyframes` animation (fade in / fade out timing of a couple images) that I obviously wish to get more complex in the future.

THIS is the reason why I looked for LESS library.

---

**Take you time... I wish to have a clear explicative answer.

Or some reference links to read.

My house isn't on fire.**

Comment: Speaking of vendor prefixing, note that *these days* it's a waste of time to use CSS preprocesors for this kind of things. Use Autoprefixer instead.

Comment: As for variables, start at the [the docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature).

Comment: I never heard of Autoprefixer before... Will look at it. I found an interesting text about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/). I'm coding in Notepad++ by hand and only by hand. It looks like I'm doing it the hard way... Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@keyframes KeyFrame_Bes_Web { 
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease_in; }
    @{Bes_ease_in_finish} { opacity: 1; }                      /* <--- Line 75 is here. */
    @{Bes_ease_out_begin} { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    @{Bes_ease_out_finish} { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Instead of `@variable` you should use `@{variable}` when using dynamic directives. (is directive the right word? dunno)

Comment: Ever been respectfully called "My Master" with a low tone voice ? :D WORKING! I could have spent a week or more to find out  this strange syntax... And don't have this time to lose! Have my gracefull respects.

Comment: «is directive the right word?» I don't know either. But will google it. ;) Thanks again.